# React: how to change startup file index.html to other html page in start_url of manifest.json

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React, I need to change the starting page index.html to some other html page (eg: person.html as stating page). I have created person.html page inside public folder and changed in manifest.json and tried. but still it is taking index.html as priority.

manifest.json:

```
{

  "short_name": "React App",

  "name": "Create React App Sample",

  "icons": [

    {

      "src": "favicon.ico",

      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",

      "type": "image/x-icon"

    }

  ],

  "start_url": "./person.html", //here i have changed and tried

  "display": "standalone",

  "theme_color": "#000000",

  "background_color": "#ffffff"

}
```

Am expecting the result as while rendering, it should not run index.html and should take other html page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780983/how-can-i-rename-index-html-in-a-create-react-app-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rename index.html in a create-react-app project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780983/how-can-i-rename-index-html-in-a-create-react-app-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using create-react-app to create the react application, you will need to eject the project to be able to rename it. Once the project is ejected, you can manually configure webpack, babel and all other dependencies. You will need to dive into the webpack settings to change this.

Without ejecting there is no other way. Please be careful as you cannot undo it.

First you will need to run:

```
npm run eject
```

in webpack.config.prod.js change filename to:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ inject: true, template: paths.appHtml, filename: 'person.html', ...)
```

You can read more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1761

### Edit:

Looks like the webpack configurations have changed in newer create-react-app versions. Here's how you would do it now:

First eject.
Then open paths.js which is found in the config folder, and change the appHtml property in the module.exports.

Here is the modified exports object for you:

```
module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appPath: resolveApp('.'),
  appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/person.html'),  //Change only this line
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
  appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
  proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  publicUrl: getPublicUrl(resolveApp('package.json')),
  servedPath: getServedPath(resolveApp('package.json')),
};
```

Comment: In webpack.config, i have added new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
            fileName: "person.html"
          }..... Now am  getting error as Could not find a required file index.html inside public folder.....   still it is searching for index.html page only...

Comment: I have edited my answer for the new create-react-app versions. The configuration settings changed a little. After ejecting, you only need to change that one line which I have commented on. If it works, please mark this as complete and upvote so that it helps someone

Comment: I think you need to change in both places `webpack.config.js` and `paths.js`