# How change the path to index.html in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Commonly, `index.html` is in `"public"` folder and `index.js` searches for this file.
But I need that the `index.html` was located in another folder.

If it is needed I did't use `create-react-app` and made configuration by myself

Where can I change the path to index.html?

Comment: I think this question related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50780983/4019273